# Moving space between partitions

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, partitioning

In the image below there is 'Part OEM' between C and E. Do you know how to move/remove it? I need to move some space from C to E.

[image: Partitions]

Comment: Not sure if that works, but you could try to: 1. Delete E:, 2. Increase OEM to the end, 3. Shrink OEM from front (so it's small again but now at the end of the disk), and 4. Recreate E:

Comment: Did you mean that 482MB one? Just right click on it, choose delete volume, then expand C: drive

Comment: @Biswapriyo I wish it to be that easy. In context menu there is only 'help' option. Same as for each part.

Comment: @MichałWoliński Are the other options gone or just greyed out? I wouldn't bother trying to fix the problem. I can give you a solution by booting from a CD or USB-Stick, would that work for you? You should improve your question by writing "In context menu there is only 'help' option. Same as for each part." directly into your question.

Answer (score 0):

try to delete the OEM partition by CMD.exe:

1.run the cmd.exe as administrator
2.type diskpart and click Yes
3.refer to the following steps to delete the OEM partition

(1)**list disk** (show all of the disks on your computer)
(2)**select disk a** (a is the disk that contains OEM partition)
(3)**list partition** (show all of the partitions on the hard drive)
(4)**select partition b** (b is the OEM partition that you want to delete)
(5)**delete partition override**
(6)**exit**

Please make sure that the OEM partition will not affect your system, or backup it before you delete it.